# How to configure the login services?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am using [this package](https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown) to provide better login design for `accounts-ui`.
When I run my project, it shows me "No login services configured" instead of "sign_in" that i usually see when i use `accounts-ui` package

I did what they mentioned in the package page and added the following code in the client side:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
    passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_AND_OPTIONAL_EMAIL'
});
```

I still see "No login services configured".

What is the problem here?

Comment: Is your code located in the `/server` directory, or wrapped in `Meteor.isServer()` checks?

Comment: @NickBull it is located in /client/fileName.js